# Django inspectdb unable to inspect table - relation doesn't exist error

Tags: django

So, what I'm trying to achieve is to map the tables I have in my postgres database to django models.
I've tried using `inspectdb`, but it keeps throwing errors and I'm out of ideas on how to fix it. Here is the code I ran:

```
python3 manage.py inspectdb account
```

And the output it gives me is:

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey and OneToOneField has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from django.db import models
# Unable to inspect table 'account'
# The error was: relation "account" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "account" LIMIT 1
```

What I think is going on here is that for some reason the inspectdb is wrapping the table name with double quote which is incorrect to `psql` syntax and this is the immediate cause of the error.

I have checked if the table is accessible for the database user that django uses and when I tried running the same query, just without the quotes on table name it gave me a correct output:

```
database=# SELECT * FROM my_schema.account LIMIT 1;
 id | username | email | password_hash | confirmed | last_login_time 
----+----------+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------------
(0 rows)
```

Django database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'database',
        'USER': 'db_admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'temporary_password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Have anyone encountered this problem and solved it? Or maybe I'm using the tool in a wrong way?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Show us your  DATABASES config

Comment: @iklinac I can be sure it connects to correct database, because it used to fail due to wrong password, but I changed it and now it connects without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your schema to searchpath

```
    'OPTIONS': {
        'options': '-c search_path=myschema'
    }
```